# PreparedStatement, DDL change doesn't change ResultSet on Db2

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I have a Java-based application where I issue a query that uses a `PreparedStatement`.  These prepared statements are cached in my connection implementation layer and are later discarded based on an eviction routine.

The issue I have stumbled onto is that if I generated a `PreparedStatement` with the following query:

```
SELECT FUNCTION(..) as A, T.* FROM table t WHERE ...
```

If I later issue an `ALTER TABLE table ...` statement and the above prepared gets reused, if I add a new column in the `ALTER` that column isn't visible in the prepared statement's result set.  If the statement expires and therefore is closed or if the statement is manually closed after the `ALTER` and I use a new prepared statement, I get the new column that was added.

I have a few questions:

1. Can someone explain what's going on as I don't observe this with other vendors?
2. Is this caching with the `PreparedStatement` controlled at the driver or database level?
3. If it's at the driver level, can this behavior be disabled?

**UPDATE**

We are explicitly connecting to an IBM Db2 11.5 instance on Linux using the following driver:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcc</artifactId>
            <version>11.5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IBM supplied jdbc driver then the following IBM statement can answer your question, as relates to the IBM type 4 jdbc driver. If you have other layers involved, different answers might apply.

> The IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ does not check whether
> the definitions of target objects of statements in the internal
> statement cache have changed. If you execute SQL data definition
> language statements in an application, you need to disable internal
> statement caching for that application.

This statement comes from the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_cjv00007.html). In other words, when using `ALTER TABLE....` for a table for which a cached preparedStatement already exist, there is no automated invalidation of the cached preparedStatement .

You could disable the preparedStatement caching (by adjusting `maxStatements` property) or perform the DDL adjustments when the app is not running, or  use some cache clearing technique.

It is unclear from your question whether or benchmarking has been done to prove that statement caching is beneficial for the workload.

Comment: I checked the database metadata and the statement pooling isn't enabled, and after passing both `maxStatements` and `statementCacheSize` as `0` for good measure, the prepared statement continued to use the table structure from before the `ALTER`.  I've updated the original post with the driver details in case that makes a difference.

Comment: You should be using the type 4 driver, at the latest fixpack , specifically 11.5.7.0 (driver is db2jcc4.jar build is 4.31.10 ). That will reduce the chances of some driver mistake that's been subsequently fixed. However, the information in the IBM link is supposedly correct. IF you have a doubt, then open a support ticket with IBM.